# A more efficient way to import multiple CSV files from a directory

Tags: powershell, csv

There must be a more efficient way to import multiple CSV files from a directory where the name of the file contains Services_Results*.csv into one variable with unique entries. I'm thinking of looping through all the files in the directory that match the file name with a wildcard then just importing the lines where Success is on the field.

```
$Success0 = Import-Csv -Path "\\FILE05\Users\USER001\+Projects\Chrome\Services_Results.csv" | Where-Object {$_.Status -eq "Success"}
$Success1 = Import-Csv -Path "\\FILE05\Users\USER001\+Projects\Chrome\Services_Results_150601.csv" | Where-Object {$_.Status -eq "Success"}
$Success2 = Import-Csv -Path "\\FILE05\Users\USER001\+Projects\Chrome\Services_Results_150602.csv" | Where-Object {$_.Status -eq "Success"} 
$Success3 = Import-Csv -Path "\\FILE05\Users\USER001\+Projects\Chrome\Services_Results_150602_b.csv" | Where-Object {$_.Status -eq "Success"} 
$Success4 = Import-Csv -Path "\\FILE05\Users\USER001\+Projects\Chrome\Services_Results_150602_c.csv" | Where-Object {$_.Status -eq "Success"}
$Success5 = Import-Csv -Path "\\FILE05\Users\USER001\+Projects\Chrome\Services_Results_150603_a.csv" | Where-Object {$_.Status -eq "Success"}

$PCList = $Success0 + $Success1 + $Success2 + $Success3 + $Success4 + $Success5
$PCList = $PCList.PC | sort -Unique
Write-host "PCList" $PCList.count
```

Comment: $PCList.PC is the field that contains the PC name. I couldn't figure out how to make a list of unique entries when there was more than one column of data.

Answer (score 2):

From Get-Help Import-CSV:

```
-Path <String[]>
    Specifies the path to the CSV file to import. You can also pipe a path to Import-Csv.

    Required?                    false
    Position?                    1
    Default value                None
    Accept pipeline input?       true (ByValue)
    Accept wildcard characters?  false
```

So Import-CSV will accept multiple values for -Path from the pipeline:

```
$PCList = 
Get-ChildItem '\\FILE05\Users\USER001\+Projects\Chrome\Services_Results*.csv' |
Select -ExpandProperty FullName |
Import-CSV |
Where-Object {$_.Status -eq "Success"}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using PowerShell Background Jobs to speed up the process? I haven't tested this code, but try to read an understand the pattern. I think you'll appreciate how much it can speed up the process, if you're importing large CSV files.

```
### Create an empty array to hold Background Jobs.
$JobList = @();

### Get a list of CSV files.
$FileList = Get-ChildItem -Path \\FILE05\Users\USER001\+Projects\Chrome\*Services_Results*.csv;

foreach ($File in $FileList) {
    ### Start a new Background Job for each file
    $JobList += Start-Job -ScriptBlock { Import-Csv -Path $args[0] | Where-Object -FilterScript { $PSItem.Status -eq 'Success'; } } -ArgumentList $File.FullName -Name $File.Name;
}

### Wait for all the jobs to complete.
Wait-Job -Job $JobList;

### Receive the results of the jobs.
$ResultList = Receive-Job -Job $JobList;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do what you want quite neatly with the way you're already doing it, but using a wildcard and a ForEach loop:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem "\\FILE05\Users\USER001\+Projects\Chrome\*.csv"
$PCList = $files | ForEach { (Import-Csv $_ | Where Status -eq "Success") }

$PCList = $PCList | sort -Unique -Property PC
Write-Output $PCList
Write-Output $PCList.Count
```